# modlue not found while adding @zeit/next-css

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I keep getting module not found error after yarn add @zeit/next-css. The error is:

```
error - ./node_modules/@ant-design/icons/lib/components/AntdIcon.js:20:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'classnames'
```

My next.config.js looks like:

```
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css')

if(typeof require !== 'undefined'){
    require.extensions['.css']=file=>{}
}

module.exports = withCss({})
```

and my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "antd": "^4.13.1",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "next": "10.0.8",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1"
  }
}
```

I remembered seeing someone complain about the same issue online, but I could not find it anymore.

Comment: The error if for AntdIcon not @zeit/next-css, please put your html code

Answer (score 1):

`@zeit/next-css` has been deprecated and wasn't updated for the past 2 years. Consider using Next.js built-in CSS support instead (see [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)).

Comment: Does next.js have support for revising the css for external component? For instance, I am using the built-in component from the Antd UI library, but according to the specification of next.js I am not able to change the css of the components in Antd because it requires me to change the filename of the components.

Comment: @penny, yep, Next.js requires files to be CSS modules (`*.module.css`). So need to find a workaround.

Comment: @penny, it seems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66554660/change-background-color-of-header-to-less-variable-nextjs-less-antdesign) is the same issue discussed.