# Change background color of header to LESS variable (nextjs + less + antdesign)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, less, antd

Lets say i have Header.js

```
...
    const MainHeader = () => {
      return (
        <Header>
          <Menu theme="dark" mode="horizontal">
            <Menu.Item key="1">nav 1</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">nav 2</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3">nav 3</Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Header>
      );
    };
...
```

And i want to change color of that header simplest way is probably this

```
...
    const MainHeader = () => {
      return (
        <Header style={{background:"black"}}>
          <Menu style={{background:"black"}} theme="dark" mode="horizontal">
            <Menu.Item key="1">nav 1</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">nav 2</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3">nav 3</Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Header>
      );
    };
...
```

but what i want to do is to use variables (instead of black) from var.less but i cant find a way how to do it.
Of course i can use Header.module.less to create new class and use it in Menu or Header but i will need to add `!important` because otherwise ant defaults will be used. Or if you know any better way how to edit ant design please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#Ant-Design-Less-variables), you can override styles by changing global variables `@layout-header-background` and `@menu-dark-bg`

All less variables for dark theme could be found [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/36bcaaef858fe9a77b50e24b09d84d92dc55d163/components/style/themes/dark.less)